# Strange behavior of Frame?

Tags: frame

How can I prevent 'Frame' to ignore data at the lower x-Range?

[image]

Again, thanks a lot, Harald

EDIT:

here are the data:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p2712deki1jswks/ois.dat.zip?dl=0

EDIT2: And here is the working code as requested. It works with random data as well as with the first 100 or 200 lines of the data. But not with all of the data (5680 lines). But the data are okay... Would be very happy to hear what I am doing wrong...

```
infil = "ois.dat"; list = OpenRead[infil]; data = 
        Import[list, "Table"]; 
i := 4; values = data[[All, i]];
plotset = {PlotStyle -> Thick, AxesStyle -> Thick, 
          FrameStyle -> Thick};
DistributionFitTest[values];
colum[1] = "Conductivity 1 [mS/m]";
colum[2] = "Inphase 1 [ppt]" ;
colum[3] = "Conductivity 2 [mS/m]"; 
colum[4] = "Inphase 2 [ppt]";
colum[5] = "Conductivity 3 [mS/m]"; 
colum[6] = "Inphase 3 [ppt]" ;
colum[7] = "Inv.Cond. 1 [mS/m]" ;
colum[8] = "Inv.Cond. 2 [mS/m]";
colum[9] = "Inv. Thick[m]" ;
colum[10] = "Inv.RMS[%]";
DFT = DistributionFitTest[values, Automatic, "HypothesisTestData"];
      {xmin, xmax} = MinMax[values];
fdist = FindDistribution[values];
max = Maximize[{PDF[fdist, x], xmin <= x <= xmax}, x];
level = 5/100 max[[1]];
f1 = Plot[{PDF[DFT["FittedDistribution"], x], level}, {x, xmin, xmax},
     PlotRange -> Full];
f2 = Show[Histogram[values, 100, "PDF"]];
sol = Quiet[
     NSolve[{PDF[DFT["FittedDistribution"], x] == level, 
     xmin <= x <= xmax}, x], NSolve::ifun];
f3 = Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{x, level} /. sol]}];
f4 = Show[f3, f1, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 1.5}}, 
     Axes -> True, ImageSize -> Full];
Show[f2, f4, Evaluate@plotset, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 16], 
 AxesStyle -> Blue,(* PlotLabel\[Rule]sol,*) FontSize -> 22, 
 ImageSize -> Full, Epilog ->
  Inset[Framed[Column[{"Schnittpunkte: ", sol, "Daten: ", colum[i]}], 
    RoundingRadius -> 5], Scaled[{0.85, 0.85}], 
   Background -> LightBlue]]
```

Comment: Can you provide some data? So one (i.e. I) can only guess: maybe an explicit setting of `PlotRange`may help

Comment: instead of putting your data at a site where one has to create an account and password and figure how to navigate and download your file then unzip it and save it somewhere and go through all this just to help you, you should make a MWE. i.e. a self contained example with small data to show the problem. You can make random data or any other way to show the problem.

Comment: I'd also be interested in what `f2` and `neu` are exactly. Thanks!

Comment: @Nasser Actually one doesn't need to make an account -- they make it look like you do, but you can close the "sign up" window and just download it.  That said, the rest of your points are absolutely valid -- this is not the most convenient way for people to help here.